# How do I install pyaudio without any errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice-recognition, pyaudio, chatterbot

I have installed Microsoft visual c++ 2015 edition as well as 2017 edition. I have install Microsoft visual studio community edition along with python development kit.

I have individually installed them one at a time and tried to run command:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

After installing VC 2015 and 2017 edition, both the times, the error was like this:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Waaberi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e5le61j0\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Waaberi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-adj3zivl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

---

After installing Microsoft Visual Studio Community version, the error changes like this:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n80doxlb\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q1i9vfma\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

---

How do I solve this? How can I install pyaudio without these errors?

Comment: Why you want to use VS for python?

Comment: Tip: For large code blocks, highlight your code/error/whatever then click the `{}` button on the editor.

Comment: I was trying to install that pyaudio package, but I had already installed the latest version of VC++ but it kept popping up that error, so I tried every type of resource I could find. Turns out that I only had to install the python version 3.6x, since the current pyaudio package is not compatible with 3.7x.  P. S: I'm new here, I'm still figuring out the components of of this hub. Tips will be appreciated. Thank you.